# Simple Ruby variable mutability

Tags: ruby

I'm a bit confused with the following Ruby code:

```
a = "hello"
b = a

a #=> "hello"
b #=> "hello"

a.upcase!

a #=> "HELLO"
b #=> "HELLO"

a = a.capitalize

a #=> "Hello"
b #=> "HELLO"
```

Why is it that `a.upcase!` affects the value of `b`, but `a = a.capitalize` does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that a.upcase! affects the value of b

Well, this can be explained using `#object_id`.

```
a = "hello"
b = a
a.object_id # => 72370120
b.object_id # => 72370120
a.upcase!
a.object_id # => 72370120
b.object_id # => 72370120
```

As you can see, that you have same *string* object(`object_id` values are telling it) is referenced by the 2 local vars `a`, `b`. Now `#upcase!` method always change the original object. That's why you are seeing same change by inspecting `a` and `b`.

> but a = a.capitalize does not?

But, `#upcase` first take copy of the *string* object, then do changes on the new object, not the original one. Same can be seen using `#object_id` again.

```
a = a.capitalize # => "Hello"
b.object_id # => 72370120
a.object_id # => 74438640
```

Now see the object ids are different. `b` still holding the old *string* object, but `a` is now holding the new *string* object.

Answer (score 4):

Do `a.capitalize!` this will affect `b` too.

**What is happening?**

When you do `capitalize` a *copy* of string with first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase is returned. Which you are freshly assigning to a variable `a`. However `b` is still pointing to old value of `a` i.e. `HELLO`.

However when you do `capitalize!` the string itself get modified and hence `b` will get affected too.

Example:

```
a = "hello"
b = a
a.capitalize
# => "Hello"
a
# => "hello" # remains unchanged
b
# => "hello" # which is the actual value of a
a.capitalize!
# => "Hello"
a
# => "Hello" # a's value is changed
b
# => "Hello" # which is the actual value of a
```